# Array Becomes Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the weirdest bug right now; I built this function made to remove xss vulnerabilities from the output of my server, and when parsing MongoDB result objects (with subdocuments in the schema), the array properties promptly change from array to undefined. See the code and the trace below:

Code:

```
function xss(value){
  if(typeof value === "object" && value !== null){
    return xssObjectEscape(value);
  }else if(typeof value === "string"){
    return xssStringEscape(value);
  }
}

function xssStringEscape(text) {
   return text.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').
     replace(/</g, '&lt;').  // it's not necessary to escape >
     replace(/"/g, '&quot;').
     replace(/'/g, '&#039;');
}

function xssObjectEscape(object) {
  for (var prop in object) {
    if(typeof object[prop] === "string"){
      object[prop] = xssStringEscape(object[prop]);
    }else if(Array.isArray(object[prop])){
      console.log("xss Array");
      console.log(`${prop}: ${JSON.stringify(object[prop])}`);
      console.log(object[prop]);
      console.log(typeof object[prop]);
      console.log(object[prop].constructor);
      console.log(object[prop].constructor.name);
      console.log(object[prop].length);
      for(let i = 0 ; i < object[prop].length ; i++){
        object[prop] = xss(object[prop][i]);
      }
    }else if(typeof object[prop] === "object" && object[prop] !== null){
      xssObjectEscape(object[prop]);
    }
  }
  return object;
}
```

Trace:

```
xss Array
save: [null,null,null,null]
[ [Function: notify],
  [Function: notify],
  [Function: notify],
  [Function: notify] ]
object
[Function: Array]
Array
4
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at xssObjectEscape (/var/www/smq/services/secure/xss.js:30:39)
    at xssObjectEscape (/var/www/smq/services/secure/xss.js:34:7)
    at xssObjectEscape (/var/www/smq/services/secure/xss.js:34:7)
    at xssObjectEscape (/var/www/smq/services/secure/xss.js:34:7)
    at xss (/var/www/smq/services/secure/xss.js:5:12)
    at filter.user.then (/var/www/smq/handlers/session.js:29:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

Any idea why this may happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  for(let i = 0 ; i < object[prop].length ; i++){
    object[prop] = xss(object[prop][i]);
  }
```

You're overwriting the value of `object[prop]` with `undefined` inside your loop. You probably meant to assign to `object[prop][i]`, but instead you're completely overwriting the value at `object[prop]` with the `undefined` returned from `xss`.

The next loop iteration tests the stop condition `i < object[prop].length`, and raises an exception. All of your logging isn't helping, because you're doing it at the wrong point. You should be inspecting the value of `object[prop]` **after** you overwrite it inside your loop.

Note that you should probably just be using `map` instead of your `for` loop:

```
object[prop] = object[prop].map(xss)
```

Comment: See I knew this was a silly thing like such. Cheers!